# Does deleting the root partition affect the home partition?

Tags: partition, hard-disk, external-hdd

But then I remembered home is !mounted! in /home and / is root

Here's what I want to do..
I have an hdd with 4 partitions.

- boot
- swap
- root
- home

I delete the first one, then the second, then hesitated to delete the third.. what if.. home gets deleted too? I mean I know it's just a partition, and when the system is on, it's mounted in /home

But I'm not sure and I don't want to make a horrific 400GB mistake.

Comment: For a safe place to learn the formatting, see https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/646/117549

Comment: Only f you issue rm -rf / them yes the mounted partitions will be affected (I am not exactly know what are you thinking to do).... Dropping the only the / partition from the disk should be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that a partition is JUST a block in storage, if it's mounted then you can edit the stuff in it..

When I installed arch linux, I had to mount the root partition into the usb live arch's /mnt folder, so root was (/mnt), then I mounted the home partition into a "mkdir'd" folder in /mnt/home <-- so home was mounted in a root folder..

just because you mounted a partition in a folder doesn't mean that partition has MOVED to the folder and is now living there, so.. with the partitions "umount'd" it's safe to delete any partition because they're just blocks in storage and their locations are separate.

Didn't matter in the end, made a mistake, deleted all them gigabytes, am sad now, got super depressed, sometimes winging it isn't the best idea, always have a plan kids. and adults.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't erase the partition or format the files system of home nothing should happen

Anyway you should have a safe back up of your home directory to do that safely. **It's highly recommended**

Deeper, The mount of the partitions in the operating system is managed by the /etc/fstab file. You could watch inside with this command :

```
more /etc/fstab
```

The fact is the new version of Linux manage the partition files system with UUID, no more through the devices directory as exemple /dev/sda1 for partition one and /dev/sda2 for partition 2 ( This last management is old school). You could have more information here :
[Control mounting and unmounting of filesystems](https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/l-lpic1-104-3/)

Answer (score 0):

> Does deleting the root partition affect the home partition?

No.

That is, in fact, how I do my upgrades (Debian). I have the following partitions:

```
/
/home
[swap]
```

Whenever a new major release is available, I install it over `/`, and keep `/home` as it is.

For me, I have never had any issues whatsoever with this approach.